AssertionError: Class ProductSerializer missing "Meta.model" attribute although I have Meta() class with model attirbute
I'm trying to simply post data using this django serializer but I'm constantly receiving the error Class ProductSerializer missing "Meta.model" attribute. Do you know if I'm missing something:
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class  Meta:
        model : Product 
        fields : ['title','image','likes']

This is my model:
class Product(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
image = models.CharField(max_length=200)
likes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

Error from my console

You are using colon instead of an equal to sign. It should be model = Product :
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class  Meta:
        model = Product 
        fields = ('title','image','likes')

